# Converting a JSON request to a row in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have the following string converted to JSON:

```
data = {"MessageCode":1502,
"MessageVersion":4,
"ApplicationType":0,
"TokenID":0,
"ExchangeSegment":1,
"ExchangeInstrumentID":22,
"ExchangeTimeStamp":1309954231,
"Bids":[{"Size":21,"Price":1999.15,"TotalOrders":2,"BuyBackMarketMaker":0},
{"Size":20,"Price":1999.1,"TotalOrders":1,"BuyBackMarketMaker":0},
{"Size":40,"Price":1999.05,"TotalOrders":1,"BuyBackMarketMaker":0},
{"Size":185,"Price":1999,"TotalOrders":6,"BuyBackMarketMaker":0},
{"Size":7,"Price":1998.8,"TotalOrders":2,"BuyBackMarketMaker":0}],
"Asks":[{"Size":1,"Price":1999.8,"TotalOrders":1,"BuyBackMarketMaker":0},
{"Size":3,"Price":1999.85,"TotalOrders":1,"BuyBackMarketMaker":0},
{"Size":34,"Price":1999.9,"TotalOrders":2,"BuyBackMarketMaker":0},
{"Size":199,"Price":2000,"TotalOrders":10,"BuyBackMarketMaker":0},
{"Size":1,"Price":2000.05,"TotalOrders":1,"BuyBackMarketMaker":0}],
"Touchline":{"BidInfo":{"Size":21,"Price":1999.15,"TotalOrders":2,"BuyBackMarketMaker":0},
"AskInfo":{"Size":1,"Price":1999.8,"TotalOrders":1,"BuyBackMarketMaker":0},
"LastTradedPrice":1999.9,
"LastTradedQunatity":12,
"TotalBuyQuantity":145954,
"TotalSellQuantity":81287,
"TotalTradedQuantity":114118,
"AverageTradedPrice":1999.65,
"LastTradedTime":1309954224,
"LastUpdateTime":1309954231,
"PercentChange":0.6365580576173091,
"Open":1997.65,
"High":2006.6,
"Low":1989.1,
"Close":1987.25,
"TotalValueTraded":null,
"BuyBackTotalBuy":0,
"BuyBackTotalSell":0},
"BookType":1,
"XMarketType":1,
"SequenceNumber":476310325663841}
```

I want to convert data["Bids"][0][0] (i.e. Size:21) into one column then data["Bids"][0][1] into another and data["Bids"][0][2] into third....... likewise I want 37 such columns namely:

```
1: Date (now.day)
2. Time (convert ExchangeTimeStamp to current time)
3. ExchangeInstrumentID
4-33. [bid_size1, bid_price1, bid_totalorder1, bid_size2, bid_price2, bid_totalorder2, ....bid_size5, bid_price5, bid_totalorder5, ask_size1, ask_price1, ask_totalorder1, ...ask_size5, ask_price5, ask_totalorder5]
34. LastTradedPrice
35. LastTradedQunatity
36. LastTradedTime (converted to present timestamp)
37. LastUpdateTime (converted to present timestamp)
```

This is what I have tried:

```
rename = {'TotalOrders':'_totalorder'}
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d['Bids']).rename(columns=rename).add_prefix('bid'), 
            pd.DataFrame(d['Asks']).rename(columns=rename).add_prefix('ask')], axis=1)
```

This gives me 6 columns and not 6*5 = 30 columns.
pls help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
data = """{
    "MessageCode": 1502,
    "MessageVersion": 4,
    "ApplicationType": 0,
    "TokenID": 0,
    "ExchangeSegment": 1,
    "ExchangeInstrumentID": 22,
    "ExchangeTimeStamp": 1309954231,
    "Bids": [
        {
            "Size": 21,
            "Price": 1999.15,
            "TotalOrders": 2,
            "BuyBackMarketMaker": 0
        },
        {
            "Size": 20,
            "Price": 1999.1,
            "TotalOrders": 1,
            "BuyBackMarketMaker": 0
        },
        {
            "Size": 40,
            "Price": 1999.05,
            "TotalOrders": 1,
            "BuyBackMarketMaker": 0
        },
        {"Size": 185, "Price": 1999, "TotalOrders": 6, "BuyBackMarketMaker": 0},
        {"Size": 7, "Price": 1998.8, "TotalOrders": 2, "BuyBackMarketMaker": 0}
    ],
    "Asks": [
        {"Size": 1, "Price": 1999.8, "TotalOrders": 1, "BuyBackMarketMaker": 0},
        {
            "Size": 3,
            "Price": 1999.85,
            "TotalOrders": 1,
            "BuyBackMarketMaker": 0
        },
        {
            "Size": 34,
            "Price": 1999.9,
            "TotalOrders": 2,
            "BuyBackMarketMaker": 0
        },
        {
            "Size": 199,
            "Price": 2000,
            "TotalOrders": 10,
            "BuyBackMarketMaker": 0
        },
        {
            "Size": 1,
            "Price": 2000.05,
            "TotalOrders": 1,
            "BuyBackMarketMaker": 0
        }
    ],
    "Touchline": {
        "BidInfo": {
            "Size": 21,
            "Price": 1999.15,
            "TotalOrders": 2,
            "BuyBackMarketMaker": 0
        },
        "AskInfo": {
            "Size": 1,
            "Price": 1999.8,
            "TotalOrders": 1,
            "BuyBackMarketMaker": 0
        },
        "LastTradedPrice": 1999.9,
        "LastTradedQunatity": 12,
        "TotalBuyQuantity": 145954,
        "TotalSellQuantity": 81287,
        "TotalTradedQuantity": 114118,
        "AverageTradedPrice": 1999.65,
        "LastTradedTime": 1309954224,
        "LastUpdateTime": 1309954231,
        "PercentChange": 0.6365580576173091,
        "Open": 1997.65,
        "High": 2006.6,
        "Low": 1989.1,
        "Close": 1987.25,
        "TotalValueTraded": null,
        "BuyBackTotalBuy": 0,
        "BuyBackTotalSell": 0
    },
    "BookType": 1,
    "XMarketType": 1,
    "SequenceNumber": 476310325663841
}"""

import json

df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(data))
df["ExchangeTimeStamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["ExchangeTimeStamp"], unit="s")
df["Touchline.LastTradedTime"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df["Touchline.LastTradedTime"], unit="s"
)
df["Touchline.LastUpdateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df["Touchline.LastUpdateTime"], unit="s"
)
asks = df["Asks"].explode()
df = df.explode("Bids")
df["Asks"] = asks

a = df.pop("Asks").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("Asks_")
b = df.pop("Bids").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("Bids_")

df = pd.concat([df, a, b], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   MessageCode  MessageVersion  ApplicationType  TokenID  ExchangeSegment  ExchangeInstrumentID   ExchangeTimeStamp  BookType  XMarketType   SequenceNumber  Touchline.BidInfo.Size  Touchline.BidInfo.Price  Touchline.BidInfo.TotalOrders  Touchline.BidInfo.BuyBackMarketMaker  Touchline.AskInfo.Size  Touchline.AskInfo.Price  Touchline.AskInfo.TotalOrders  Touchline.AskInfo.BuyBackMarketMaker  Touchline.LastTradedPrice  Touchline.LastTradedQunatity  Touchline.TotalBuyQuantity  Touchline.TotalSellQuantity  Touchline.TotalTradedQuantity  Touchline.AverageTradedPrice Touchline.LastTradedTime Touchline.LastUpdateTime  Touchline.PercentChange  Touchline.Open  Touchline.High  Touchline.Low  Touchline.Close Touchline.TotalValueTraded  Touchline.BuyBackTotalBuy  Touchline.BuyBackTotalSell  Asks_Size  Asks_Price  Asks_TotalOrders  Asks_BuyBackMarketMaker  Bids_Size  Bids_Price  Bids_TotalOrders  Bids_BuyBackMarketMaker
0         1502               4                0        0                1                    22 2011-07-06 12:10:31         1            1  476310325663841                      21                  1999.15                              2                                     0                       1                   1999.8                              1                                     0                     1999.9                            12                      145954                        81287                         114118                       1999.65      2011-07-06 12:10:24      2011-07-06 12:10:31                 0.636558         1997.65          2006.6         1989.1          1987.25                       None                          0                           0        1.0     1999.80               1.0                      0.0       21.0     1999.15               2.0                      0.0
0         1502               4                0        0                1                    22 2011-07-06 12:10:31         1            1  476310325663841                      21                  1999.15                              2                                     0                       1                   1999.8                              1                                     0                     1999.9                            12                      145954                        81287                         114118                       1999.65      2011-07-06 12:10:24      2011-07-06 12:10:31                 0.636558         1997.65          2006.6         1989.1          1987.25                       None                          0                           0        3.0     1999.85               1.0                      0.0       20.0     1999.10               1.0                      0.0
0         1502               4                0        0                1                    22 2011-07-06 12:10:31         1            1  476310325663841                      21                  1999.15                              2                                     0                       1                   1999.8                              1                                     0                     1999.9                            12                      145954                        81287                         114118                       1999.65      2011-07-06 12:10:24      2011-07-06 12:10:31                 0.636558         1997.65          2006.6         1989.1          1987.25                       None                          0                           0       34.0     1999.90               2.0                      0.0       40.0     1999.05               1.0                      0.0
0         1502               4                0        0                1                    22 2011-07-06 12:10:31         1            1  476310325663841                      21                  1999.15                              2                                     0                       1                   1999.8                              1                                     0                     1999.9                            12                      145954                        81287                         114118                       1999.65      2011-07-06 12:10:24      2011-07-06 12:10:31                 0.636558         1997.65          2006.6         1989.1          1987.25                       None                          0                           0      199.0     2000.00              10.0                      0.0      185.0     1999.00               6.0                      0.0
0         1502               4                0        0                1                    22 2011-07-06 12:10:31         1            1  476310325663841                      21                  1999.15                              2                                     0                       1                   1999.8                              1                                     0                     1999.9                            12                      145954                        81287                         114118                       1999.65      2011-07-06 12:10:24      2011-07-06 12:10:31                 0.636558         1997.65          2006.6         1989.1          1987.25                       None                          0                           0        1.0     2000.05               1.0                      0.0        7.0     1998.80               2.0                      0.0
```